# 'cannot open git-upload-pack' error in Eclipse when cloning or pushing git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit, atlassian-sourcetree

I am not able to clone or push to a git repository at Bitbucket in Eclipse:

[image: Error 'cannot open git-upload-pack']

It's weird, because a day before I didn't have any problem. I have downloaded the sts 3 times with no luck. This error keeps showing. Also I have installed SourceTree and it says 'This is not a valid source path / URL':

[image: Error 'This is not a valid source path / URL' in sourcetree]

If I use git commands to import the project, it works, but I wan't to use EGit for this task, since I am a newbie with git.

I don't know if this has to do with it, but in the same directory I have the android-adt-bundle. This one works pretty well, but the project lies on GitHub and not Bitbucket. Also, I'm working with another person and he is able to fetch and push data from and to the Bitbucket repository. I have read lots of posts but none of them have helped me out.

I'm using Windows 7 btw.

Comment: Can you please try git clone using git Bash. That will give more verbose output.

Comment: I can do the import with git. And it works fine, the problem is the egit. There must be any file or something missing or corrupted somewhere.

Comment: We really need to protect this question!

Comment: Had the same problem today with Eclipse. I just restarted Eclipse and tried again.

Comment: Had the same issue, in my case it worked when I configured SSO for my org on my github Personal Access Token(PAT). You can configure SSO on PAT by going to your: github settings > Developer settings > Tokens (classic) > Configure SSO > choose your organization

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I made it work thanks to the [steps outlined in the Eclipse forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=648905&S=9bcfa96ab726d744d41a19c7fb02d723#msg_648905):

## Set up the SSH key stuff

1. Download and install mysys git according to the github instructions at http://help.github.com/win-git-installation/
2. In C:/Users/you/ssh hide any existing keys (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) in a subdirectory. If the ssh directory does not exist, create it. Of course, "you" is your username as the OS knows you.
3. From the start menu, run Git-Bash command shell (a regular DOS command shell will not work).
4. In the Git-Bash shell generate an rsa key based on your email (the one you registered at github):
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@wherever.com"
   and enter your pass phrase and confirm when asked.
5. The previous step should have created C:/User/you/ssh/id_rsa.pub which you can now open in a text editor and copy. At github, go to account settings, SSH Keys, add a key and paste this in the key box.
6. In Git-Bash again (notice the back-ticks in the next line):

   `` eval `ssh-agent`
   ssh-add C:/User/you/ssh/id_rsa
   ssh git@github.com ``

Here is what you just did: You ran the ssh-agent which is needed by ssh-add. Then you used ssh-add to make note of the location of your key. Then you tried to ssh to GitHub. The response to this last command should be that you have successfully authenticated at GitHub but that you don't have shell access. This is just an authentication test. If the authentication was not successful, you'll have to sort that out. Try the verbose version:

`ssh -v git@github.com`

Assuming this worked....

## In Eclipse, configure the remote push

1. *Window* > *Show View* > *Git* > *Git Repositories* will add a repository explorer window.
2. In the repository window, select the repository and expand and right-click *Remotes* and choose *Create Remote*.
3. Copy the GitHub repository URI from the GitHub repository page and paste it in the URI box.
4. Select ssh as the protocol but then go back to the URI box and add "git+" at the beginning so it looks like this:

   git+ssh://git@github.com/UserName/ProjectName.git
5. In the *Repository Path* box, remove the leading slash
6. Hit *Next* and cross your fingers. If your get "auth fail", restart Eclipse and try step 5 again.
7. When you get past the authentication, in the next dialog select "master" for source ref, click "Add all branches spec" and "Finish".

Instead of using SSH git@github.com I did it with SSH git@bitbucket.org.

Now I can push and import without any problem.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm using Eclipse + GitHub on Windows 7 and keep getting the git-upload-pack error.

Comment: Nothing seems to work for me , because of project constrain i have to use windows 10 + java 7+ jboss 7.1.1( build on eclipse keepler ) + git . i tried almost everything but keep getting error git upload pack during pull/push or clone . Can anybody help here ????

Comment: This is the solution which worked for me after about 6 hours of banging my head. Thank you.

Answer (score 131):

### Might also be bad SSL cert, fix the server

If you have a GIT server with an outdated or self-signed SSL cert fix the server, afterwards everything should run fine.

### Insecure Hotfix: Let the client accept any certificate

The following solution is just a mere hotfix on client side and should be avoided **as it compromises security** of your credentials and content. There is a detailed explanation for this in "[How can I make git accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate?noredirect=1&lq=1)" which offers more complex and more secure solutions you can try out if the following works in general.

In my case it was Eclipse using a different storage for the git config as the command line does and thus not having the option

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

set (which I set using command line for the repo [for working with invalid/untrusted SSL cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate)).

Adding the option insides Eclipse immediately resolves the issue. To add the option

1. open preferences via application menu **Window => Preferences** (or on OSX **Eclipse => Settings**).
2. Navigate to **Team => Git => Configuration**
3. click `Add entry...`, then put `http.sslVerify` in the key box and `false` in the value box.

Seems to be a valid solution for Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), 4.5.x (Mars) and 4.6.x (Neon) on different Operating systems.

Comment: This helped me a lot - simplest solution too.  FYI, when on the git configuration screen, click `Add entry...`, then put `http.sslVerify` in the key box and `false` in the value box.

Comment: Still valid solution for Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) on MAC OS X Yosemite

Comment: Still valid solution for Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Eclipse Neon seems to default to /Users/<myuser>/.gitconfig and thus might be finally getting rid of this issue.

Comment: Still valid solution for Neon.1 on Windows 10

Comment: But beware: Done in the preferences like this, you set the configuration globally for your whole user-account... So no SSL-Verification is done anymore. This could lead to security-problems!

Comment: @shorif2000 Neon.1-3 and Oxygen behave the same concerning this. Perhaps your problem isn't bad SSL certs?

Comment: Tried all options on STS (Spring Tools Suite). Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 19):

It happens due to the following Reasons:

1) Firewall.

2) Network Issues.

3) Proxy Settings Mismatch

4) Connected through different Router - which is not authorized within the network.

5) Git Proxy Authentication Details

Comment: In my case, it was my firewall blocking.

Comment: In my case my Git proxy authentication details were incorrect

Comment: in my case, sitting behind firewall and had changed my proxy password, updated password under Preferences>>General>>NetworkConnections

Comment: Regarding 2), one instance of "network issues" is just the internet connection not working. Once again, a git-related error message does not explain what's wrong at all.

Comment: In my case, I wasn't connecting to the "dev network". Check your wifi connectivity to the correct network.

Answer (score 10):

I added `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` to `eclipse.ini` and it's working. 
I use java 1.7

Comment: Note: You have to restart Ecplise for this to take effect like @Hardik Lotiya mentioned

Answer (score 9):

After struggling for a couple of hours, I found that git config file was not updated when I added the entry `sslVerify = false` in my Eclipse.

I solved my problem by navigating to my `.git` directory and updating the `config` file to :

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
```

Comment: Worked for me. Next step was that eclipse required username and password.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same issue with eclipse 2020-12. In Preferences->Git I changed "Http Client" to "Java built-in HTTP" and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Worked for me with eclipse 2021-03

Comment: This worked for me with STS 4 (Eclipse 4.9.0.RELEASE)

Answer (score 6):

One cause of this is having Fiddler2 configured to decrypt HTTPS traffic.  Close Fiddler2 and it should work fine.

Comment: Alternatively you could add Fiddler's root cert to the Java cacerts file.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I got same problem with existing repository.when I try to fetch from upstream not able Fetched object and got problems eclipse: cannot open git-upload-pack.

for me following solution work after adding TLS version in **eclipse.ini** file

**Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2**

For java7 need to add TLSv1.1 and for java8 need to TLSv1.2

Note: Need to restart eclipse once above configuration added.

Answer (score 4):

This issue can be caused when you have a local firewall which is preventing your application from being able to send any network traffic away from your machine. I.e. Outbound traffic or egress traffic rules.

Please try disabling your firewall for a quick test to see if this fixes your issue.  If it does then setup the appropriate firewall policy for the application you are trying to use to push or pull to a git repository.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it turned out that global proxy settings in "Preferences->Network connections" were interfering with git. Which is kind of confusing, because git has dedicated property for proxy configuration. Anyway, I've added repository host to "Proxy bypass" list and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I faced "git-upload-pack not permitted" error in STS4 while fetching Bitbucket repository. I struggled for **many many hours** only to realize we need to use password generated with "Create app password" in Bitbucket (and not our own set password)

URL to generate password: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/new

Use this password in "Clone a Git repository" in STS4

Answer (score 1):

I just got this same error, "cannot open git-upload-pack", in Eclipse with a BitBucket repo trying to do a pull or a push.
I resolved it by switching local branches (Team/Switch To) to the master branch and doing a pull, and then switching back to the branch I was working on and pulling again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SR2 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS and was trying to access an internal GitHub using HTTPS. 
Unfortunately, my underlying JVM with which Eclipse was started experienced problems with the self-signed certificate of the server. Switching to a different JVM for Eclipse got the HTTPS connection to our GitHub working.

Create a simple Eclipse starter that uses a different JDK, e.g. with OpenJDK:
`/Eclipse_Kepler_4.4.2/eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin`

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar problem. I just followed the below steps
1. Team > Remote > Configure Fetch from upstream...
2. Provide the https: bit bucket uri then Save and Fetch.
3. Reset the latest commit in your project. Team > Reset > Select the latest commit from remote folder
4. Then synchronize the workspace. Team > Synchronize (in synchronize perspective)
5. Right click on project and overwrite the local copy.
6. Click on Pull icon.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution to this in Eclipse Mars 4.5.2:
Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Repository Settings -> AddEntry
Key: http.sslVerify
Value: false

Answer (score 1):

For those who still have this problem, and none of the above solutions worked for you:
Update your versions of java and Eclipse.
In my case, I updated from java 7 to java 9, and Eclipse Mars to Eclipse Oxygen, and this problem was solved !!!

Answer (score 1):

Add https.sslVerify as false...when you use https connection for importing from git

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and a quick fix to your issue is to make sure that you set your JVM option in the eclipse.ini file to use jre7. Older Jre's come with an old local policy file and this will return errors. One quick note also is that you need to point to your javaw not java.

-vm
c:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre745\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

Answer (score 0):

I had my proxy settings set up in Eclipse and wasn't connected via ssh, which was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried all those methods but it didn't work then a workmate told me that Putty Key Generator  used to generate keys with  1024 bits but now Putty generate 2048 bits keys by default ,  so you just need to change the "Number of bits in a generated key"  and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be caused by wrong system time (by a couple of years), making the Git's certificate invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the Network settings from `Native` to `Manual`, restart and the error is gone.

I'm using RAD 8.0.4.3 with and old version of EGit connected to TFS/Git. ;-)

[image: Eclipse Network Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message because I had a different user than what the repo expected in my git config.

This would obviously trigger the SSL Cert failures mentioned above.

Fixing to the correct user resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

to fix SSL issue you can also try doing this.

Download the NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA2.crt from the bitbucket server and add it to the ca-bundle.crt

ca-bundle.crt needs to be copied from the git install directory and copied to your home directory

**cp -r git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt ~/**

then do this. this worked for me
**cat NetworkSolutionsDVServerCA2.crt >> ca-bundle.crt**

**git config --global http.sslCAInfo ~/ca-bundle.crt**

**git config --global http.sslverify true**

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue by disabling `IPv6` on the `network configuration`

[Screenshot of my network configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S9Zo.png)

> Note that I use a VPN connection. If you do too, you must restart it.
>   I'm pretty sure that it will work even if you don't use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The repository owner should give you a contributor permission:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

For the Eclipse running on IBM JDK the following 2 lines are mandatory in eclipse.ini after -vmargs:

-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same issue on Spring Tool Suite (STS) and turns out, all i had to do was update my proxy settings in STS network config.

window > preferences > General > Network Connections and on the dropdown select "**Manual**" from "**Native**".

Here, just add your proxy url, port and your credentials for **http** and **https** by clicking on edit.
Apply and close.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and after some research found that we need to ***create an access token in github*** and use it instead of the password which we have been using till now while git push and pull.

Github developer blog explaining the password deprecation: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/

I have documented the steps here - you may try it out and see if it works for you.
https://webfuse.in/blogs/issues-troubleshooting/git-upload-pack-not-permitted-on-error-while-git-pull-and-git-push/

Thanks. This looks like an evergreen Question as I am answering after 7 years along with other valid answers!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The error occurred suddenly while working. In my case it looked like an account problem or server side problem.

I sign out and signed in again in Bitbucket repository from web browser and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can occur when there is no connection to remote origin. For me it was simply dropped connection to vpn. In workspace/.metadata/.log

```
     cannot open git-upload-pack
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://xxx.repository.host.pl/groupYYY/project.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PullOperation$PullJob.run(PullOperation.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
    ....
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:213)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx.repository.host.pl
```