# Unable to push to repository in stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

[image]

I am not able to check in my code.I am getting this failure message attached in the snapshot.

I am using eclipse version 4.4 to perform this operation.

Comment: If you want check a code you need to use `pull`, not 'push', try not to use dedicated IDE Git tools, try to do using `git bash`

Comment: You may want to take a look at the following answer, it looks like the same kind of issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25917888/1356730