# cannot open git-receive-pack

Tags: eclipse, github

I'm using github via eclipse since two years. Everything worked fine all time. Today I tried to push to github and get:

```
cannot open git-receive-pack
```

as an error message. There is also a huge discussion on github concerning that issue. It seems to me that pushing to github is completly impossible in the moment.
How to attack that issue ?
Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['cannot open git-upload-pack' error in Eclipse when cloning or pushing git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813847/cannot-open-git-upload-pack-error-in-eclipse-when-cloning-or-pushing-git-repos)

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I found a workaround that will do for me:
The commit Step is left to eclipse, as it works fine.
The push step is by ssh from console. In preparation for console-push I generated an ssh-key and copied it to my settings in my github-account.
The only thing left is to to say

```
git push
```

in the main directory of the repository clone.

Comment: my solution too, but works without generation of ssh-key

Answer (score 1):

I also got this issue in eclipse, I followed below steps as given on my blog:

https://sachin4java.blogspot.in/2018/03/git-cannot-open-git-receive-pack.html

Comment: tried configuration from console and from within eclipse. Both don't work. Still:    git: cannot open git-receive-pack

Answer (score 0):

About the reason of the problem with 'git push' command, you will find the solution at https://superuser.com/questions/1297583/git-push-failing-with-fatal-httprequestexception-encountered

Personnally, i've solved the problem by updating the Git Credential Manager.

But i have still it through Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by upload my java version from 7 to 8 and download latest version of Git