# Issue while cloning Git repository with Cyberark: "cannot open git-upload-pack"

Tags: git, cyber-ark

I am new to cyberark and one of our user is facing the following error..please help me how can i resolve this issue?

when we connect to Cyberark and integrate Git with sqldeveloper , we are getting the below error

[image]

Getting the error " cannot open git-upload pack error"

[image]

Comment: Are you cloning? Pushing?

Comment: When do they get this error? when trying to validate which project, etc. Are they running the program for the first time, or did something change on their system recently? Does anyone else get the same error when trying the same thing? There really isn't enough to go on here.

Comment: to answer your question :when we connect to Cyberark and integrate Git with sqldeveloper we are getting the error. We are using this feature to connect cyberark with git for the first time and very first time we are getting this error
Everyone in our team getting the same error

Comment: cloning @GregBurghardt

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to issues with the SSL certificate issued by the server from which you are cloning the Git repository. Since you are cloning from GitHub, and I literally just went to the site, Firefox does not report the SSL certificate has issues.

Other culprits include:

- Firewalls
- General network issues
- Proxy settings

A related question has some good suggestions: ['cannot open git-upload-pack' error in Eclipse when cloning or pushing git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25917888/3092298). There is currently no accepted answer for that question. The error you are getting can have a number of causes, but they all appear to be network related.

Make sure you can browse to the repository on GitHub in a normal web browser. If you can't, or the browser reports SSL certificate issues, then that could be an indication this is an SSL certificate problem.

Comment: so do you mean this is certification issue and not related to cyberark ? @Greg Burghardt

Comment: Thank you so much for your support !