# VCS Problem : cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: git, teamcity, cicd

[image: Error Screen]

Using teamcity CI/CD, getting this error while configure the VCS using Azure DevOps repository.

tried using different username password for authentication and access token too no luck

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @JimRedmond Yes, it's behind proxy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813847/cannot-open-git-upload-pack-error-in-eclipse-when-cloning-or-pushing-git-repos