# How to clone from Bitbucket on Eclipse behind an auth proxy

Tags: eclipse, git, proxy, bitbucket

I'm having problems to clone a git repository from bitbucket on eclipse, the fact is that I can clone from other sites like github, but not from bitbucket. The auth proxy on my company allows me to go out only with http and https, so I cannot use ssh.

The url I am using to clone in eclipse is: https://mybituser@bitbucket.org/mybituser/test-bitbucket.git

I have eclipse configured to work behind the auth proxy, *Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections.*

I've tested this on eclipse kepler and juno and shows the same error.

When I try to clone from bitbucket, I complete the wizard until the last step(view branches, selecting destination folder, etc) but when I hit finish appears the error dialog:

**https://bitbucket.org/mybituser/test-bitbucket.git: cannot open git-upload-pack**

Anyone knows what can be happening here?

Thank you,

Comment: Doe BitBucket give you a URL you can clone via https?

Comment: Yes, in fact is the one in the question (https://mybituser@bitbucket.org/mybituser/test-bitbucket.git) I think is something related with bitbucket, because with github everything goes well.

Comment: That is an SSH URL. You can't simply prepend it with `https` to get around SSH being blocked. From BitBucket, is there a cloneable URL that begins with `https`?

Comment: OK, here are the URLs that Bitbucket gives you when you try to clone:
https url: (`git clone https://mybituser@bitbucket.org/mybituser/test-bitbucket.git`)
ssh url: (`git clone git@bitbucket.org:mybituser/test-bitbucket.git`)

Comment: This other Stack Overflow question might be of some help: [How Can I Resolve:“can not open 'git-upload-pack' ” error in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077016/how-can-i-resolvecan-not-open-git-upload-pack-error-in-eclipse)

Comment: I saw this question too before publish my question, but I think the problem is not the URI, I can see the branches info in the step 2. If the URI was the problem, I could not see the branches. What drives me crazy is that I can clone from others, but not from bitbucket.