# Getting cannot-open-git-upload-pack-error-in-eclipse-when-cloning

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I am getting **cannot open git-upload-pack** error in eclipse when cloning, I tried all solutions available online but still getting this error while cloning. Interestingly IntelliJ Idea works fine(but don't want to ask employer to buy license of IntelliJ Idea) for this repository. I am using eclipse Oxygen with JDK 8

Some images of errors and settings of eclipse

*Image of error that I get while cloning*
[image]

*Detailed error message*
[image]

*Git configurations*
[image]

**What I tried**

1. All solutions in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813847/cannot-open-git-upload-pack-error-in-eclipse-when-cloning-or-pushing-git-repos) post
2. Adding "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1" to eclipse.ini as suggested on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096644/266827) answer
3. Changing Eclipse and JDK version.

I am out of options. Not sure what else should I try.

Comment: If possible, try a protocol other than HTTPS. Can you reproduce this issue with the current versions of Java, of Eclipse and of EGit (the screenshot shows you are using Java 8u121 and Eclipse 4.7.3)?

Comment: @howlger: I tried Eclipse Photon and JDK 9 but still same error.