# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX with Twitter4J

Tags: java, security, ssl, twitter4j

I'm trying to run a simple example from the examples set provided by Twitter4J. I'm getting the following error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d3c26678 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=99f8151f
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d3c26678-99f8151f d3c26678-99f814f5 d3c26678-99f814f5 d3c26678-99f814f5], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.1}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:82)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getUserStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:246)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$5.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:218)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:533)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:137)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 23 more
onException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[Tue Jun 17 05:22:47 EDT 2014]Waiting for 2000 milliseconds
[Tue Jun 17 05:22:47 EDT 2014]Twitter Stream consumer-1[Waiting for 2000 milliseconds]
```

which I think is being raised by the attempt to call

`POST https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json`

I'v entered this link in the browser (firefox)  and Confirmed Exception of the certificate, however it gives me: `category_access_denied`

I've saved the keystore file to the computer and tried to list the type using the following command:

```
keytool -list -keystore userstream.twitter.com
```

and I get the following error:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

Any help with this is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Saved which keystore file from where?

Comment: sorry the certificate! I've saved the certificate!

Comment: The certificate by itself is not a keystore, you should create an empty keystore and [import that certificate into it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore).