# m2e with ssl certificate-based authentication

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ssl-certificate, m2e

**TL;DR**

How to make Eclipse's built-in Maven connect to an HTTPS repository that uses certificate-based authentication?

It seems that `m2e` is able to find the keystores, but unable to connect. Command-line Maven works like a charm using exactly the same keystores. `Run as -> Maven build` works with external Maven and not with the embedded one.

**Problem**

I have a Maven project with a dependency. That dependency is available in a repository that uses SSL certificate-based authentication in addition to regular username-password combination. I need to make it work in Eclipse Luna, with the built-in Maven. All I am able to get is `handshake_failure`. Investigation of the logs shows that the built-in Maven is unable to find a matching certificate.

When I use `Run as -> Maven build` with an external Maven, or command-line Maven, it successfully connects to the repository and fetches the artifact exactly as needed.

The interesting thing is, both external and embedded Mavens have the same version (3.2.3).

**Setup**

I pass these parameters through `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=java.cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=******
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=private.cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=******
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

The `trustStore` file contains:

- the whole certificate chain for the repository I connect to (the chain ends with a self-signed certificate), one of them being stored under the alias `repository.location.url` (literal repository location here, e.g. *myrepository.com*)
- certificate for maven central

The `keyStore` file contains an imported PKCS certificate under an alias of the repository.

There seems to be no problem at all with the setup, as the command-line Maven works. If I use external Maven or command-line one, it works. If I swich to embedded one (which is always used for resolving dependencies), `handshake error` shows up.

**What am I doing wrong?** I might be missing something completely obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My first guess would be proxy settings in Eclipse but even those should be using the VM's keystore :-/ Odd. Which version of Eclipse, Java and m2e?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, m2e 1.5.0 (with Maven 3.2.1) and 1.6.0 (3.2.3), Java 1.7 and 1.8 (both jdk and jre)

Comment: And you added the `-D` options after the line `-vmargs`?

Comment: Your problems is probably the same as installing Eclipse plug-ins from an Update Site with a self-signed certificate: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/19/installing-eclipse-plug-ins-from-an-update-site-with-a-self-signed-certificate/ Your approach above looks correct.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Yes, those `-D` things appear after `-vmargs`. The VM that Eclipse uses is able to find the files and list the certificates (with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`), but it fails to find the correct one. Outside of Eclipse's VM, those things work perfectly.

Comment: Feels like a bug. Try to report it at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=m2e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem: Eclipse could not connect to external maven repository using embedded maven installation in case the repository requires a client SSL certificate.

The problem was solved by upgrading to latest jvm (in my case - 1.8.0u52) and upgrading Eclipse m2e plugin to version 1.6.1 (with Eclipse version 4.4.0).

Comment: seems that the m2e update did the trick, 1.6.1 does not appear to have this problem

Comment: m2e 1.13.0 (with eclipse 2019.09) here and it still doesn't work... Commandline maven works without issue

Answer (score 5):

**Options that didn't work for me**

- Installing certificate to java > jre > lib > security > cacerts
- Providing cacerts in java run configuration vm arguments
- Updating eclipse to latest versions like mars or neon
- Updating maven plugin for eclipse to 1.7.0

**Steps that resolved the issue for me**

- [Download certificate file](http://docs.bvstools.com/home/ssl-documentation/exporting-certificate-authorities-cas-from-a-website) & add in eclipse at **Preferences > Remote Systems > SSL > Add**
- Clear .m2 > repository folder of all existing files
- Open eclipse, right-click on project and Select **Maven > Update Project**. Choose **Force Update of Snapshots/Releases**

**updated on 9/19/2017**

- If nothing else works, [Installing the certificate to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4325263/3357935) on your machine @ java > jre > lib > security > cacerts can help

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked after I did  Maven > Update Project as advised.

Comment: m2e 1.14.0 (with eclipse 2019.12) here and it still doesn't work... Command line maven works without issue. Both eclipse and command line running same JVM with certificate installed

Answer (score 1):

In your run configurations select your maven build and then select the JRE tab at the top of the dialog.  Put your SSL parameters into the VM arguments text-area.

that's what fixed it for me.

Comment: The question is about the embedded Maven, i.e. the one that Eclipse uses internally to update the project. The external one, i.e. one used for run configurations, works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by setting external maven in eclipse.
Eclipse->Window->Preferences->Maven->Installations->Add