# Convert .cer certificate to .jks

Tags: java, certificate, jks, cer, java-security

I need to convert a `.cer` file to a `.jks` file.
I saw a few questions about it, but haven't seen a solution to what I need.

I don't need it in order to add it to my local certificates, but as a file to upload to a server.
I also need to do it only once, and not programmatically.
There's this thread [Converting .cer to .jks using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131210/converting-cer-to-jks-using-java) and the author says he had done it successfully, but I couldn't comment to his last reply as I don't have enough reputation, nor could I send him a personal message and ask him.

So if anyone knows of a simple way to do so, I'll be glad to hear.

Answer (score 95):

`keytool` comes with the JDK installation (in the `bin` folder):

```
keytool -importcert -file "your.cer" -keystore your.jks -alias "<anything>"
```

This will create a new keystore and add just your certificate to it.

So, you can't *convert* a certificate to a keystore: you **add** a certificate to a keystore.

Comment: Hi, somewhere I can find the keystore created? On the certmgr?

Comment: @viviramji the keystore will be created as a file, in the folder where you run this command

Answer (score 11):

Just to be sure that this is really the "conversion" you need, please note that `jks` files are keystores, a file format used to store more than one  certificate and allows you to retrieve them programmatically using the Java security API, it's not a one-to-one conversion between equivalent formats.

So, if you just want to import that certificate in a new ad-hoc keystore you can do it with [Keystore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/), a graphical tool. You'll be able to modify the keystore and the certificates contained therein like you would have done with the java terminal utilities like `keytool` (but in a more accessible way).

Answer (score 4):

Use the following will help

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts \
-alias keyAlias \
-file server.cer \
-keystore cacerts.jks \
-keypass changeit
```

Answer (score 3):

Export a certificate from a keystore:

```
keytool -export -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

Comment: I think this does the reverse of what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me brilliantly

First, create a PKCS12 keystore :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my-app-certificate.crt -inkey my-app-certificate-private.key -out my-app-keystore.p12 -name my-app
```

This will require a **password**

`-name` is the alias of the private key entry in keystore.

Next, convert the PKCS12 keystore to JKS keytstore using keytool command :

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my-app-keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore my-app-certificate.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

To view the JKS file contents:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore my-app-certificate.jks
```

**Reference**: [Steps to create a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL](https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/post/steps-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-openssl)

This will request for the password entered when creating the PKCS12 keystore