# Rest api in java using https

Tags: java, rest, web-services, https, rest-security

when I am creating `Restservices` in java using `GET`, `POST` etc then I am requesting them using 
`http protocol`. as soon as i use https it gives error.

for eg :  `http://localhost:8080/demorest/webapi/aliens` is working properly.

but when I query same using `https`

```
https://localhost:8080/demorest/webapi/aliens
```

I get error `site can not provide secured connection`

what modification is required to make them compatible with `https`.

Comment: Bro..I think they deleted the docs. "Document not found" error I m getting.

Comment: Check https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars1902/configuring-the-rest-api-by-using-ssl-certificates-849379723.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned you are new to APIs here is a detailed answer for you.

Answer is based on assumption that you are using tomcat server. There is 4 step approach to have application running on https, red below

1. Get an SSL certificate or Generate a self-signed SSL certificate
2. Enable HTTPS in application
3. Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
4. Distribute the SSL certificate to clients.

If you dont already have ssl certificate generate yourself using keytool.
Keytool is a certificate management utility provided together with the JDK, so if you have the JDK installed, you should already have keytool available.

Let's open our Terminal prompt and write the following command to create a JKS keystore:

> keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore
>   keystore.jks -validity 3650 -storepass password

To create a PKCS12 keystore, and we should, the command is the following:

> keytool -genkeypair -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype
>   PKCS12 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650 -storepass password

Let's have a closer look at the command we just run:

```
genkeypair: generates a key pair;
alias: the alias name for the item we are generating;
keyalg: the cryptographic algorithm to generate the key pair;
keysize: the size of the key. We have used 2048 bits, but 4096 would be a better choice for production;
storetype: the type of keystore;
keystore: the name of the keystore;
validity: validity number of days;
storepass: a password for the keystore.
```

When running the previous command, we will be asked to input some information, but we are free to skip all of it (just press Return to skip an option). When asked if the information is correct, we should type yes. Finally, we hit return to use the keystore password as key password as well.

```
What is your first and last name? 
    [Unknown]:  What is the name of your organizational unit? 
    [Unknown]:  What is the name of your organization? 
    [Unknown]:  What is the name of your City or Locality? 
    [Unknown]:  What is the name of your State or Province? 
    [Unknown]:  What is the two-letter country code for this unit? 
    [Unknown]:  Is CN=localhost, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct? 
    [no]: yes 

Enter key password for <tomcat> 
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

Verify the keystore content
To check the content of the keystore following the JKS format, we can use keytool again:

> keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks

To test the content of a keystore following the PKCS12 format:

> keytool -list -v -storetype pkcs12 -keystore keystore.p12

Convert a JKS keystore into PKCS12

Should we have already a JKS keystore, we have the option to migrate it to PKCS12; keytool has a convenient command for that:

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore
>   keystore.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12

2.) To Enable https in your project

If you have a application.properties file

```
server.port=8443

server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat

security.require-ssl=true
```

If you have application.yml file

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias: tomcat
    key-password: password
  port: 8443
```

To achieve in application, we need to extend the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class, since the `security.require-ssl` property has been deprecated.

if you are on older version then you can skip below mentioned code.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requiresChannel()
            .anyRequest()
            .requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

3.) Redirect http to https

Now that we have enabled HTTPS in our Spring Boot application and blocked any HTTP request, we want to redirect all traffic to HTTPS.

Spring allows defining just one network connector in `application.properties (or application.yml)`. Since we have used it for HTTPS, we have to set the HTTP connector programmatically for our Tomcat web server.

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

4.) Distribute the SSL certificate to clients
When using a self-signed SSL certificate, our browser won't trust our application and will warn the user that it's not secure. And that'll be the same with any other client.

It's possible to make a client trust our application by providing it with our certificate.

Extract an SSL certificate from a keystore
We have stored our certificate inside a keystore, so we need to extract it. Again, keytool supports us very well:

> keytool -export -keystore keystore.jks -alias tomcat -file
>   myCertificate.crt

Make a browser trust an SSL certificate
When using a keystore in the industry-standard PKCS12 format, we should be able to use it directly without extracting the certificate.

I suggest you check the official guide on how to import a PKCS12 file into your specific client.

If deploying the application on localhost, we may need to do a further step from our browser: enabling insecure connections with `localhost`.

In Chrome, we can write the following URL in the search bar: `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` and activate the relative option.

Import an SSL certificate inside the JRE keystore
To make the JRE trust our certificate, we need to import it inside cacerts: the JRE trust store in charge of holding all certificates that can be trusted.

First, we need to know the path to our JDK home. A quick way to find it, if we are using Eclipse or STS as our IDE, is by going to Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. If using IntelliJ IDEA, we can access this information by going to Project Structure > SDKs and look at the value of the JDK home path field.

Then, from our Terminal prompt, let's insert the following command (we might need to run it with administrator privileges by prefixing it with sudo):

> keytool -importcert -file myCertificate.crt -alias tomcat -keystore
>   $JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

you can refer project on github [here](https://github.com/ThomasVitale/spring-tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-https)

Comment: Buenas, en tu proyecto. En la carpeta resources tenés dos files,
myCertificate.crt
springboot.p12 
El primero me queda claro que es el que creaste vos, pero el segundo ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, your rest services might run on Tomcat or Spring Boot so should read their documentation, you can also use a different https service like nginx that proxies all or parts of the requests from https to http.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check https protocol using the same port as 8080? in most of the cases http (8080) and https(8443 or 443) use different ports.
2. If port is correct then import the certificate.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928213/5662508

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you can give the sever you are using, also would be always nice if the java version, frameworks(if any) and their version and in this case of-course the server and the server version.

In the link mentioned [here on DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes) you can find an example of how to set up `https` locally with tomcat server in a  java application, else you can also try with a more generic article not specific to java [here on freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** You can create a keystore using java keytool;

**Command** : keytool -genkey -alias {any-name} -keyalg RSA -keystore {path to store the keystore}

**Step 2 :** You can go to your server config file such as conf/server.xml for Tomcat and uncomment the 8443 setting and then add the following in the end before tag closing;

keystoreFile="{path to keystore}"
keystorePass="{Password you set while creating the keystore}" **/>**

**Step 3 :** Now restart the server and hit "https://localhost:8443/demorest/webapi/aliens".

Happy coding!