# How to handle secured connection for update check?

Tags: install4j, java-security

We had changed our security to allow only https connection for every server call. Now also the update check action has to handle the https connection. Instead to activate the option 'Accept all SSL certificates' we want to use our own certificates placed in a truststore. How can we do this? At time we are using install4j 6.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to import the certificate with the "keytool" command:

[How to import a .cer certificate into a java keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore)

Comment: We have created a truststore containing our certificates but I don't get it how to provide this to the "Check update" action?

Comment: If you import into the default keystore, it should work automatically. The download actions in install4j just open a URLConnection, all SSL handling is provided by the JRE. I have never tried to do this, though.

Comment: We had created our own truststore and added system properties via "Run script" action to the installer to set the location to this truststore: `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "[path-to-truststore]")` and `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "[my-password]")`. That works fine for our purpose. The only thing to do is set the truststore data variables as hidden one to prevent them to be logged in the logfile or `i4jparams.conf` file. The "Set Variable" and "Run script" action logs the changes of installer variables, right? So we have to implement our own action?

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I have answered your other question about hiding values from the log file.