# Setup SSL using Spring-Boot and Jetty

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, jetty

I have a spring-boot project that is run using jetty, I specifically have in my gradle

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.8.RELEASE") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

I would like to setup SSL and have registered for it and am now in possession of `.ca-bundle` `.crt` `.p7b` `.csr` and `.key` files. And additionally I would like to accomplish this by using `@Configuration` class instead of `application.properties` however I do not know the first thing about setting up SSL. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or provide a code snippet that would allow my spring boot project to use SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to add your certificates to a keystore in JKS format. This is the format used in java based web servers for storing certificates. You can use [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326346/2065796) or any other appropriate for your certificates format.

2) Put the generated file into `src/main/resources` folder of your project.

3) Make your web server use the new keystore.

In spring boot it will be easy as spring automated this process via `.properties`/`.yml` configurations.

Here is the example with `.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:your-keystore.jks
    key-store-password: your-strong-pass
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    keyAlias: your-alias
```

Each property corresponds to the entries you entered on the first step. Port should be set to `443` as it is default port for SSL connections.

**Note:** There is no point of doing this in `@Configuration` class as the recommended way is only properties file. Find more details [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl).

Comment: I got all the way to last step, but when I launch the server I am told `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Jetty servlet container` `Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.` any idea what that is? I made my jks using command `Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/keytool.exe  -import -alias jetty -file my_certificate.crt -keystore
  keystore.jks -storepass some_password`

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem. But try removing this line `keyStoreType: PKCS12` ( the default one would be `JKS`). You can also check this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/java-certificate-issue-ioexception-derinputstream-getlength-lengthtag-109-too-big-761505154.html