# keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: DER not found

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, keytool

Hi i am new to SSL handshake . I have downloaded the server certificate from browser and trying to make a keystore using keytool . The certificate i am storing as .cer with der encoding . but i am getting following

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: DER not found
```

i have tried below commands

```
  keytool -importkeystore -v -srckeystore certificate.cer -srcstoretype DER- destkeystore avg_clientcerts.keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -storetype JKS
```

and changing certificate with .der extension

```
keytool -importkeystore -v -srckeystore certificate.der -srcstoretype DER -destkeystore avg_clientcerts.keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS -storetype JKS
```

getting error as

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: DER not found
java.security.KeyStoreException: DER not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.loadSourceKeyStore(Main.java:2020)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1074)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:366)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:359)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DER KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 4 more
```

This is how i am importing the certificate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sv4R.jpg)

Comment: What is DER? The only supported keystore types I'm aware of are JKS and PKCS11. And a certificate file is not a keystore. You seem to be using the wrong commands, or to be making them up.

Comment: can you tell me how can i make call to https url from my java program . I have downloaded server certificate from browser . Steps will be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand from your question, you are trying to import public certificate to your application to enable secure communication between your application and the server you are trying to access, if the server you are trying to access have a certificate signed by a global CA, then you probably should not have to do this, but seems, it doesn't.

Then what you should do, not create a keystore instead import public key to your already existing keystore.

In short your command should be something similar to following.

```
keytool -importcert -file certificate.der -keystore avg_clientcerts.keystore.jks -alias "<<domain_name>>"
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326346/1869101%20here) is a much detailed explanation about this process