# Install SSL on Tomcat with certificate .cer

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

My question is whether it is possible to add SSL to a Windows Server with Tomcat 7 installed using only a **.cer** file.

I have a client that uses SSL in your applications with ISS and whenever you need to install SSL on your ISS server only install this **`.cer`** file: But as I did an application with Tomcat for it and I need to protect that application with HTTPS I asked for a certificate and it I sent this .cer file.

I have already tried to generate the .JKS file and add it to Tomcat in some ways and with none I was successful. Ex:

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore example.jks -trustcacerts -file certificate.cer
```

With this I generate the jks file and map it to tomcat and it happens that it does not work. I know the Tomcat settings are fine because I did a test generating the file using genkey which returns me a .keystore file and with that it works.

**Edit:**

Connector in server.xml:

```
    <Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="443" 
       maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" 
       secure="true" 
       SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="C:/path/example.jks" 
       keystorePass="password"
       clientAuth="false"
       sslProtocol="TLS"
       keyAlias="root" />
```

Should I request this certificate in another format?

Has anyone gone through this and can you give me some hint at least?

Thank you.

Comment: According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore), the correct command to import a cer-certificate into a java keystore looks like this `keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"`

Comment: Hi, I tried without success, i have the same problem.

Comment: If you want tomcat to serve content over https you will not only need a certificate but a private key as well. The private key is usually either provided in PEM format or as pfx file.

Comment: Please add your tomcat server.xml to the question to get an idea of your configuration.

Comment: Dpr, I edited for add the connector.

Comment: Can you explain the private key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178704/discussion-between-allan-braga-and-dpr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: A single CER file will usually not be enough to properly configure an HTTPS-Connector in Tomcat or any other Web-/Application-Server.

Not sure how this is configured in IIS but you will always need a private/secret key to use SSL.

Basically the standard flow when using a signed certificate (not self-signed) is like this:

1. Generate a private/secret key

   ```
   $ keytool -genkey -keystore tomcat.jks -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.jks -dname "CN=<hostname>"
   ```
2. Generate a certificate signing request for this key

   ```
   $ keytool -certreq -keystore tomcat.jks -alias tomcat -file tomcat.csr
   ```
3. This signing request (the CSR file) is submitted to a signing authority and you get a signed certificate (the CER file) in return

   ```
   $ keytool -gencert -keystore root-ca.jks -alias root -infile tomcat.csr -outfile tomcat.cer -rfc
   ```
4. This certificate together with the certificate of the signing authority are imported into your keystore

   ```
   $ keytool -import -keystore tomcat.jks -file my-root-ca.cer -trustcacerts -alias my-root-ca
   $ keytool -importcert -keystore tomcat.jks -alias tomcat -file tomcat.cer
   ```

Now the `tomcat.jks` file can be used in Tomcat as keystore for an HTTPS connector.

There is no information on what your `certificate.cer` file contains in the question. To check the contents using keytool you can use this command

```
$ keytool -printcert -file certificate.cer
```

In my example above the output looks like this:

```
Owner: CN=<hostname>
Issuer: CN=My-Root-CA, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
Serial number: 222f266a
Valid from: Sat Aug 25 12:41:01 CEST 2018 until: Fri Nov 23 11:41:01 CET 2018
...
```

Maybe you could add the output to your question to get more help, if needed.