# CertPathValidatorException Java trying to connect to server database using SSL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ssl, google-cloud-sql

I have a Java application (with hibernate) that I'm trying to use in a project with Google Cloud SQL + Compute Engine, without success.

Google Cloud SQL requires me to connect to the database through SSL, using `server-ca.pem`, `client-cert.pem` and `client-key.pem`.

Before that, I connected to my database using properties:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=pass

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

How I can change this to work with SSL?

Thank you!

[EDIT]

Tried Pooja Aggarwal answer but didn't work.

Using `-Djavax.net.debug=all` I'm getting the exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

[EDIT 2]

Commands that i run for generating certs:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem \
  -name "mysqldb" -passout pass:MYPASS -out client-keystore.p12


keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client-keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 \
 -srcstorepass MYPASS -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass MYPASS
```

And then executed:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/user/cert/keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=MYPASS -jar MyApp.jar
```

PS:
I can connect using:

```
 mysql -uroot -p -h 192.00.00.00 \
    --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem \
    --ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps mentioned in this link.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

You need to mark useSSL as true and import certificates in your JDK whose steps are mentioned in above link. Then you need to set system properties.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path_to_keystore_file"); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","mypassword");
```

Import Certificate using steps mentioned in this link : [How to import a .cer certificate into a java keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore)

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: This exception:

Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

Comment: Did you import certificate in jdk?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please follow the steps mentioned in that stackoverflow link jediz's answer.

Comment: Same exception?

Comment: Yes. The same: java.security.cert.CertificateException

Comment: Do you have multiple certificates? And if yes then try to import each one using an alias.

Comment: just the 3 certificates i wrote above.

Comment: import every certificate one by one assign alias.