# Running @QuarkusTest when maven repo requires SSL auth

Tags: maven, ssl, junit, quarkus

I am working on a demo of Quarkus.io at work, and I'm facing a problem with connecting to the company Maven repo, as that uses mutual TLS for authentication.

I.e. when I run the `test`-target the `getting-started-testing` from the [quarkus-quickstarts](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts), I am faced with the following error:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResourceTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.139 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResourceTest
[ERROR] testHelloEndpoint  Time elapsed: 0.012 s  <<< ERROR!
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResourceTest]: io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.AppModelResolverException: Failed to collect dependencies for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-deployment:jar:1.2.0.Final
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.maven.DeploymentInjectionException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.AppModelResolverException: Failed to collect dependencies for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-deployment:jar:1.2.0.Final
Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.resolver.AppModelResolverException: Failed to collect dependencies for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-deployment:jar:1.2.0.Final
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-server-common-deployment:jar:1.2.0.Final -> io.quarkus:quarkus-core-deployment:jar:1.2.0.Final -> io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-core:jar:1.2.0.Final -> org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-wagon:jar:1.1.1 -> org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:3.3.3
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:3.3.3
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:pom:3.3.3 from/to corporate-public (https://maven.corporate.net/content/repositories/corporate-public): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:pom:3.3.3 from/to corporate-public (https://maven.corporate.net/content/repositories/corporate-public): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

The `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore*` properties are normally picked up by Maven from `~/.mavenrc` or `MAVEN_OPTS` environment properties, but how do I specify them for running the Quarkus tests?

It should be obvious, but I'll state it anyways - switching to use the public repos, is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" means you do not have required certificate in your keystore. Please try to add your internal(company) certificates to your keystore. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326346/175554

Comment: Hi @özkanpakdil - which keystore? 
So the downloads works for the dependencies downloaded by Maven. 
Are the test-cases using another keystore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody else has this problem, a workaround is propagating the `javax.net.ssl.*` system properties to the Maven Surefire plugin, e.g. adding these lines to the Surefire configuration:

```
<javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType>${javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType}</javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType>
<javax.net.ssl.keyStore>${javax.net.ssl.keyStore}</javax.net.ssl.keyStore>
<javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>${javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword}</javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>
```

(This answer is totally ninja'ing the information in @tveon's [Quarkus tests fails mTLS authentication against internal Maven repository](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/15461) issue in Quarkus' GitHub repo).