# Https request with mutual authentication passes with curl but fails with java

Tags: java, ssl, curl, mutual-authentication

Someone on github asked me a question regarding my library. This library provides some factory classes to easily create a sslcontext. I make sure not the share the details of the library and just share plain java code and the additional library which I used. I tried to debug it and also tried reformatting of the certificates but it does not work. The exception which I got is:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The java trustmanager is basically saying I received the certificate of the server and I just checked in your list of trusted certificates and I couldn't find a matching certificate. So I don't trust this server and therefor I am stopping this request. When I debugged it I could understand why the trustmanager throw an exception because there was no matching certificate at all which was the same as the server. However when I use the same files with curl it works, so I was not quite sure if there is an issue with the certificates and the key material, or maybe java ssl implementation has some limitations or maybe I am not configuring it correctly... I hope someone can explain me the difference in behaviour of why it fails with java and passes with curl.

**The private key content of the client:**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**The certificate chain content of the client:**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**The trusted certificate, ca**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICVzCCAcACCQCr1Uz2zH5PwzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJ
RTEQMA4GA1UECAwHRG9uZWdhbDEUMBIGA1UEBwwLTGV0dGVya2VubnkxFDASBgNV
BAMMC3RwZWFyc29uLmllMSMwIQYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhRyb290Y2VydEB0cGVhcnNv
bi5pZTAeFw0yMTAxMDgwMTQ0NDRaFw0yMjAxMDgwMTQ0NDRaMHAxCzAJBgNVBAYT
AklFMRAwDgYDVQQIDAdEb25lZ2FsMRQwEgYDVQQHDAtMZXR0ZXJrZW5ueTEUMBIG
A1UEAwwLdHBlYXJzb24uaWUxIzAhBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWFHJvb3RjZXJ0QHRwZWFy
c29uLmllMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDJ0E9LXa/6XNzm1CZ3
lHLez768tSAmrQ0qYFCiyrGhnfe+xJJAf7BSWRAUQmM7ULRj89NVMor7GyBYH1mq
1r9dI23i3KM8ZAeBN+32eifOH/TqE2QKLm2ORqBzNXsl1QTriXLR4aIs8bYUH6JP
9qGE24ncqeO1/Ry6o2DxQWEkLQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBADq/CDEC
TwmegkvOMTH7mlWWgaoVWgBU6mtUjm2fJtQOFDewicQlxa2jF3LwDwb94J5vu6Kc
NAZwLWE70+pWhhcsXWc0rbA1Ayv1xkyi8LPWqqmCbz14R2tEDuPZJxKvS0DkGKqy
De4sdJsOo2GWhYsmY6HiOPElt5ndzI5NRZ6s
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So the following curl command will successfully execute and gives me the correct response body:

```
curl --cacert ca.pem --key client-key.pem --cert client-cert.pem https://prod.idrix.eu/secure/
```

To load these files in Java I use Bouncy Castle, below is the full snippet of parsing it, loading it into TrustManager, KeyManager, creating the SSLContext and executing the request:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

    private static final BouncyCastleProvider BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    private static final JcaPEMKeyConverter KEY_CONVERTER = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER);
    private static final JcaX509CertificateConverter CERTIFICATE_CONVERTER = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String clientKeyContent = App.getContent(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client-key.pem"));
        String clientCertificateChainContent = App.getContent(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client-cert.pem"));
        String caCertificateContent = App.getContent(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ca.pem"));

        Reader reader = new StringReader(clientKeyContent);
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(reader);
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();

        PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = ((PEMKeyPair) object).getPrivateKeyInfo();
        PrivateKey clientKey = KEY_CONVERTER.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo);
        reader.close();
        pemParser.close();

        reader = new StringReader(clientCertificateChainContent);
        pemParser = new PEMParser(reader);

        object = pemParser.readObject();
        X509Certificate clientCertificateChain = CERTIFICATE_CONVERTER.getCertificate((X509CertificateHolder) object);
        reader.close();
        pemParser.close();

        reader = new StringReader(caCertificateContent);
        pemParser = new PEMParser(reader);

        object = pemParser.readObject();
        X509Certificate caCertificate = CERTIFICATE_CONVERTER.getCertificate((X509CertificateHolder) object);
        reader.close();
        pemParser.close();

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null, "password".toCharArray());
        keyStore.setKeyEntry("client", clientKey, "".toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{clientCertificateChain});
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "".toCharArray());

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, "password".toCharArray());
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", caCertificate);
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(URI.create("https://prod.idrix.eu/secure/"))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.body());
    }

    public static String getContent(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

            return bufferedReader.lines()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
    }

}
```

I am using Java 11 and Bouncy Castle, see below for the specific artifact-id:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.68</version>
</dependency>
```

So for me it is not clear why the curl command works and the setup in java fails. Did I configured something wrong, any help would be great! I tried to provide as much as details possible. The private key is a test key so it won't harm to share it here.

Comment: if I remember correctly, there is a property that need to be modified in the java.security file that you can find inside your jdk folder at the path \jre\lib\security

Comment: Do you mean `Unlimited cryptography` check within the `jre/lib/security/policy/`?

Comment: No, the file i'm talking about it's in the same folder of the default path of the java Truststore. Is your keystore path property correctly defined in configuration? Have you tried to add the certificate to the keystore like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore ? If it's a web application did you set the environment property to the keystore path file?  **This also may be useful (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871279/java-ssl-and-cert-keystore)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what the issue was and so I wanted to share with others who have this in common.

It looks like on mac os x curl is by default using the system trusted certificates and on java side this is not the case. I am not sure what the behaviour of curl is with other operating systems. `https://prod.idrix.eu/secure/` has a certificate which is signed by `DST Root CA X3` I disabled this and rerun the exact same setup as described on my initial question and the curl https request fails, just like it also failed on java side.

I disabled it from keychain as shown here:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you know which cert was leading to this problem? Cause I have a similar problem but vice versa. I am trying to POST to a server via Java app and I get an 403 all the time. However when using Postman/curl/SoapUI it works fine, so I have the assumption that I might need to add a cert or the like?

Comment: Well on java side I don't use the default truststore, I prefer to have a custom truststore which only contains the specific trusted certificate for my use case. Having this setup I could easily see that the certificate was needed on java side to be added in the truststore to get a good ssl handshake. I found it strange that I didn't need to specify the server certificate when using curl, so my assumption was that curl is by default using some trusted root ca. In that way I started to further analyse it and I found that indeed that curl was using default list of trusted certificates

Comment: So do I understand correct that you have been adding DST Root CA X3 cert to your truststore in order to be able to have a successful handshake via Java app?

Comment: Yes that's correct. However you may need to add a different certificate if the server you are calling has a different root ca. Which URL are you trying to access, is it public?

Comment: Yes it is public and it uses DST Root CA X3 as root ca as well :-) It´s: https://marketplace.syncier.com/

Comment: I have a similar issue, that´s why I was checking this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876974/mutual-tls-works-with-postman-or-soapui-but-doesnt-work-with-java-springboot maybe you have an idea why this is happening? any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I will try to help, I have dropped a comment on your question