# Mutual TLS works with Postman or SoapUI but doesnt work with Java / Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2, mutual-authentication

I try to call an endpoint via HTTP Post method which is secured via Mutual TLS which means that I am using a keystore / truststore in order to authenticate. When I try via SoapUI / Postman it works fine, of course I have to provide the keystore in my settings for both tools.

However via Springboot app it does not work (Spring Boot v2.4.4, Spring v5.3.5 using Java 14.0.2).
Here are snippets of the corresponding code (since the class is pretty big):

```
@PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        spKeyStore = FilenameUtils.normalize(spKeyStore, true);

        requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(createHttpClient());

        insuranceCertificationOutputTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        insuranceCertificationOutputTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, getMapping());

        authTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    }

@PreDestroy
private void destroy() {
    if (requestFactory != null && requestFactory.getHttpClient() != null) {
        try {
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = (CloseableHttpClient) requestFactory.getHttpClient();
            httpClient.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtil.log(LOGGER, LogLevel.ERROR, "Error closing http client");
            throw new NestedException(e);
        }
    }
}

private HttpClient createHttpClient() {

        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = null;
        if (adapterTools.isLocalEnvironment()) {
            LogUtil.log(LOGGER, LogLevel.INFO,
            credentialsProvider = new SystemDefaultCredentialsProvider();
        }
        else { //not relevant

        }

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        poolingConnManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(CONNECTION_MANAGER_MAX_PER_ROUTE); //10
        poolingConnManager.setMaxTotal(CONNECTION_MANAGER_MAX_TOTAL); //20

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
        InputStream fileInputStream = null;

        try {
            System.setProperty(SYS_PROP_KEY_STORE, spKeyStore);
            System.setProperty(SYS_PROP_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, spKeyStorePassword);
            System.setProperty(SYS_PROP_KEY_STORE_TYPE, spKeyStoreType);

            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(spKeyStoreType);
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(spKeyStore);
            keystore.load(fileInputStream, spKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());

            SSLContext sslContext =
                    SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keystore, spKeyStorePassword.toCharArray())
                            //                  .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustAllStrategy()) //tried this, didnt help
                            .build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory =
                    new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS, null,
                            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
            //tried TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3
    
            httpClient =
                    HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).disableCookieManagement()
                            .setConnectionManager(poolingConnManager).setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).build();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            LogUtil.log(LOGGER, LogLevel.ERROR, "Error initializing http client ");
            throw new NestedException(e);
        }
        return httpClient;
}

private boolean endpointHttpPostCall() {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        String KeyJson = String.format("{ \"key\": \"%s\" }", Token);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(KeyJson, headers);

        String uriString = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(Endpoint).toUriString();

        ResponseEntity<String> reply = authTemplate.exchange(uriString, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

        ...
    }
```

So as you can see I finally use the org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange Method for the POST. However I tried to replicate the behaviour via a small Java app to make sure it´s not Springboot related and it failed as well (via Apache HttpPost Method). I am receiving a 403 and I debugged TLS as well. What I found out when comparing Soap vs Springboot/Java TLS debug was the following:

The crucial part seems to be the *** CertificateRequest part, cause here when it´s failing I can see: **Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication**.

I read that this means that the servers truststore is empty, however why doesnt it fail via SoapUI then?

Another thing that stood out when comparing TLS debugs is that the Cert Authorities are listed in a clean way for Springboot like:

```
Cert Authorities:
<CN=localhost, OU=Dummy, O=OtherComp, L=Frankfurt, ST=Hessen, C=DE>
<CN=myapp.domain.company, O=MyComp, C=DE>
...
```

While for SoapUI it looks like:

```
Cert Authorities:
0000: 64 61 74<CN=localhost, OU=Dummy, O=OtherComp, L=Cologne, ST=Hessen, C=DE>
 61 3D 57 33 73   69 5A 58 5A 6C 62 6E 51  data=W3siZXZlbnQ
0010: 69 4F 69 4A 54 5A 57 35   6B 55 6D 56 78 64 57 56  iOiJTZW5kUmVxdWV
0020: 7A 64 ...
```

<CN=myapp.domain.company, O=MyComp, C=DE>
57 39  vZHVjdF92ZXJzaW9
0090: 75 49 6A 6F 69 4E 53 34   31 4C 6A 41 69 4C 43 4A  uIjoiNS41LjAiLCJ
00A0: 51 63 6D 39 6B 64 57 4E   30 51 58 4A 6C 59 53 49  Qcm9kdWN0QXJlYSI
...

I am not sure why this differs to be frank, I expect both to look equal. But of course SoapUI uses a different Java Version (which I tried to use as well for Springboot/Java, didn´t help and I haven´t compared the mentioned part).

I also read that this could mean that my keystore has not been created correctly but here also the question is why it does not fail then via SoapUI or Postman? Or am I doing anything else not properly?

So here is the SSL Debug which I modified for readability, also to remove all private infos:

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-06-10 14:10:15.471 CEST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:79|adding as trusted certificates (
"certificate" :... lots of certificates

Then:

```
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.212 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:294|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.212 CEST|SignatureScheme.java:294|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|INFO|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.217 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.218 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.218 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.241 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.241 CEST|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:633|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.241 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.242 CEST|ClientHello.java:653|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "0....",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302),....]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=api.marketplace.syncier.com
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256...]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256...]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [  
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 ..
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.354 CEST|ServerHello.java:871|Consuming ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "9B ...,
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    },
    "server_name (0)": {
      <empty extension_data field>
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed, ansiX962_compressed_prime, ansiX962_compressed_char2]
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.354 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.355 CEST|ServerHello.java:967|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.355 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:189|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:189|Consumed extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:189|Consumed extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:189|Consumed extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:160|Ignore unsupported extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:160|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:189|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.356 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:160|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:212|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:212|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:212|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.357 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.358 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.358 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:212|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.358 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.363 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:357|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "04 EF A8 05 97 22 6F 87 E2 5A FC 22 7E 89 BB 1F CC 81",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2021-03-12 15:31:23.000 CET",
    "not  after"         : "2021-06-10 16:31:23.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=api.marketplace.syncier.com",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: ocsp
           accessLocation: URIName: http://r3.o.lencr.org
        , 
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://r3.i.lencr.org/
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 14 ...
        0010: 8B 14 C2 C6                                        ....
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:false
          PathLen: undefined
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 1A 66C 65 74  ..http://cps.let
        0010: 73 ...            sencrypt.org
        
        ]]  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          serverAuth
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_Encipherment
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          DNSName: api.marketplace.syncier.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 1C 2F 4C 87 8A BE 65 82   48 92 B9 44 EE CE 14 FE  ./L...e.H..D....
        0010: D9 5F 85 7E                                        ._..
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "40 01 75 04 83 14 A4 C8 21 8C 84 A9 0C 16 CD DF",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=DST Root CA X3, O=Digital Signature Trust Co.",
    "not before"         : "2020-10-07 21:21:40.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2021-09-29 21:21:40.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://apps.identrust.com/roots/dstrootcax3.p7c
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: C4 A7 B1                                      `...
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:0
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
        CRLDistributionPoints [
          [DistributionPoint:
             [URIName: http://crl.identrust.com/DSTROOTCAX3CRL.crl]
        ]]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 22 ...                                     .org
        
        ]]  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          serverAuth
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 14 2E B3 1                                   ....
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.429 CEST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:238|Found trusted certificate (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "44 AF B0 80 D6 A3 27 BA 89 30 39 86 2E F8 40 6B",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA1withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=DST Root CA X3, O=Digital Signature Trust Co.",
    "not before"         : "2000-09-30 23:12:19.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2021-09-30 16:01:15.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=DST Root CA X3, O=Digital Signature Trust Co.",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: C4 A7 B1 A4 7B 2C 71 FA   DB E1 4B 90 75 FF C4 15  .....,q...K.u...
        0010: 60 85 89 10                                        `...
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.436 CEST|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:534|Consuming ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ServerKeyExchange": {
  "parameters": {
    "named group": "secp256r1"
    "ecdh public": {
      0000: 04 28 25 ...                                             .
    },
  },
  "digital signature":  {
    "signature algorithm": "rsa_pss_rsae_sha256"
    "signature": {
      0000: 7E 37 D2 8...
      0070: ...
    },
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.438 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:671|Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [rsa_sign, dss_sign, ecdsa_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [...]
  "certificate authorities": [CN=localhost, OU=Marketplace, O=Syncier, L=Munich, ST=Bayern, C=DE, CN=myurl.mycomp, O=mycomp, C=DE, CN=myurl.mycomp1, O=mycomp, C=DE, CN=mycomp, O=mycomp, C=DE, CN=myurl.mycomp1, O=mycomp, C=DE, CN=mycomp CA II, O=mycomp, C=DE, CN=mycomp Root CA, O=mycomp, C=DE]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.439 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:743|Unable to produce CertificateVerify for signature scheme: ed25519
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:743|Unable to produce CertificateVerify for signature scheme: ed448
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.440 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.441 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.441 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.441 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.441 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSASSA-PSS
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.441 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_pss_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.441 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.442 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.443 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:764|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.444 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:774|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.445 CEST|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.445 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:290|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.445 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:321|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.452 CEST|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:396|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 04 53 8E 83F(..
    0040: F                                              .
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.473 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:115|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.474 CEST|Finished.java:398|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 9... 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.523 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:149|Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|7A|myFunction-step-db|2021-06-10 14:10:52.525 CEST|Finished.java:535|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 53 ...
  }'}
)
```

Comment: When debugging TLS the message which seems to be the issue is: "No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead". However I do provide a proper cert I think

Comment: Can you rerun it with the following vm arguments: `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake` and share the full logs of it in your initial question? It will make it easier to see why it is failing as it will give the handshake logs

Comment: Sure, I added the debug logs, however I needed to crop a lot since it got too big to post here

Comment: Java works with indivual jvm's what works in SOAP UI, doesn't have to relate to another JVM. There are multiple ways of specifying how to find a truststore, and what I believe you intend to do is get it through a system property, but you do a setProperty and not a getProperty so spKeyStore doesn't get initialized and somehow your keystore that contains the client certificate doesn't get found.

Comment: But I do initialize the keystore through sslContext which finally is part of my sslSocketFactory -> httpClient. Isn´t that supposed to work then? And regarding your suggested getProperty: just to be clear the spKeyStore is the absolute path to my keystore file, and SYS_PROP_KEY_STORE = "javax.net.ssl.keyStore". So you are saying I need to use getProperty instead of setProperty? cause for example here its explained the way I did it: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/cadminsslclient.html

Comment: But still I think you are right that keystore somehow is not properly initialized. btw how did you spot from the logs that this is the case? cause "keystore is.." message is missing?

Comment: So the server is requesting the client certificate and the client is returning an empty list according to the logs. So my assumption would be that either the keystore/keymanager is not loaded corrected, or the keystore does not contain an entry or the object is null. If you run it in debug mode you can inspect the keymanager and see if there is an entry present

Comment: Did it work by the way? Or any other issues which are still present?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I mean, I tried many aproaches to fix it (with KeyManager, without KeyManager, hardcoded Keystore via jvm argument etc). I agree with what you said, somehow the Keystore / Keymanager is not loaded properly. I thought maybe there is a connection to the Proxy related code (Routeplanner etc) ? Or maybe I need to load the keystore is a different way?

Comment: I have an update here: Seems the sslContext is not initialized properly cause when debugging I realized that it´s using a DummyX509KeyManager though my KeyManager looks fine (the code I use now differs from this question, I will update it as soon I have solved it)

Comment: Hi @doct0re
can you please provide any help (any url) that can help me with hitting https API using mTLS from postman? right now I only have mTLS certificate with me. Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: sure, the question is what is your problem regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve it by adding / replacing this way:

```
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
    trustStore.load(fileInputStream, "changeit".toCharArray());
    
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder
                    .<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                    .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                    .build();
        
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
    poolingConnManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(CONNECTION_MANAGER_MAX_PER_ROUTE);
    poolingConnManager.setMaxTotal(CONNECTION_MANAGER_MAX_TOTAL);
   
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    builder.disableCookieManagement()
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .setConnectionManager(poolingConnManager)
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
    .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);

    httpClient = builder.build();
```

What really helped in retrospective was debugging literally everything related to SSL especially the restTemplate in case you use it. In my case this object path was key to fix: authTemplate-requestFactory-httpClient-connManager-connectionOperator-socketFactoryRegistry. Here I coud see a Property with an value like "DummyX509Keymanager" which has not been set. After I tried several things finally the KeyManager was set properly.