# Http is not a trusted server error in jmeter

Tags: performance-testing

I am facing a issue in jmeter. While replaying the script i am able to get http is not a trusted server in response with 403 forbidden error as a status code. The request is failing at login.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to supply a [client certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate) along with the request

In JMeter it can be done in 2 ways:

1. GUI mode: via [SSL Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager)
2. Non-GUI mode: via [system properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration)

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/file/with/certificate(s).p12
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=password for the keyStore file
   ```

The certificate can be converted/imported into the keystore using [keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore) or [openssl](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfhb/index.html) or application like [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)