# Rundeck Windows SSL

Tags: rundeck

Has anyone configured SSL for a windows node in rundeck? I've configured the framework properties:

```
framework.server.name = myservername.domain.com
framework.server.hostname = myservername.domain.com
framework.server.port = 4443
framework.server.url = https://myservername.domain.com:4443
```

and the rundeck-config properties:

```
server.address=myservername.domain.com
server.port=4443
grails.serverURL=https://myservername.domain.com:4443
```

What I am missing is I assume I need to import a cert into the keystore? Next steps are a bit vague since they are nix specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the keystore/truststore using java [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) command (check how to do that [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/ssl.html#configuring-ssl), on the generating keystore step), [add your cert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326346/10426011) to the keystore, copy your Keystore as Truststore, then edit the  `ssl.properties` file to aim the keystore/truststore Windows path location.

With your config posted above, you can start Rundeck indicating the `ssl.properties` file location with the `-Drundeck.ssl.config=c:\rundeck\server\config\ssl.properties` and `-Dserver.https.port=4443` attributes in your `.bat` startup script (check the `start_rundeck.bat` file model [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/windows.html#installing-on-windows)).