# consuming get API using webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, webclient

My `API` is returning below `response` when I am calling from `postman`. I am not getting proper response from webclient. I am doing something wrong. I am quite new.

```
{
    "loginAccounts": [
        {
            "name": "Oracle",
            "accountId": "16485679",
            "baseUrl": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/16485679",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "userName": "Mahima Pandey",
            "userId": "e48dbc73-97df-42de-be9f-ea49c8b24712",
            "email": "mahima.pandey@oracle.com",
            "siteDescription": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

when I am consuming using webclient.

```
public static Flux<LoginAccounts> retrieveDetails(){
        Flux<LoginAccounts> loginAccounts=null;
        WebClient webclient = WebClient.create();
        try {
        loginAccounts = webclient.get().uri(DocusignConstants.LOGIN_INFO_URL)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eX...........")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(LoginAccounts.class);
        System.out.println(loginAccounts);
        }
        catch(WebClientResponseException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return loginAccounts;
    }
```

it is simple returing `MonoFlatMapMany` .how can I get proper response?

my POJO is below.

```
@data
@Noargsconstructor
@Allargsconstructor
public class LoginAccounts {

    private String name;
    private String accountId;
    private String baseUrl;
    private Boolean isDefault;
    private String userName;
    private String userId;
    private String email;
    private String siteDescription;

}
```

if I write this line `System.out.println(loginAccounts);`it prints

```
MonoFlatMapMany
```

but if i use stram it starts giving exception

```
loginAccounts.toStream().forEach(data -> System.out.println(data));
```

Below is the exception.

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2022-06-21 11:09:50.494  WARN 20024 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [099818dc, L:/172.20.10.3:58444 - R:demo.docusign.net/162.248.186.25:443] The connection observed an error

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[na:na]
```

from postman I am getting proper response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI1zg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At fist you should solve your problem with SSL. So import your SSL cert to your certstore (take a inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore)).

Second thing is that if you are working with `Flux` it doesn't mean that the response is available immediately. You should get it somehow.
You could do something like

```
List<LoginAccounts> accounts = loginAccounts.collectList().block();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `System.out.println` for printing the output. You can use the looping to print the values.

Try with the below code:

```
loginAccounts.toStream().forEach(data -> System.out.println(data));
```

Comment: Thank you Kumaresh, actually it is throwing exception. can you pls have relook. I have edited the question

Comment: @Mahima The Endpoint you are trying to access do not have valid certifications. It can be `HTTPS` insecure.

Comment: actually I can access successfully through postman.

Comment: I have attached postman screenshot at the end of the question. I dont have privildege to attach image